# Implicit and Explicit Solution with Initial Condition $\frac{dy}{dt}+2y=1$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

$\newcommand{\diff}{\frac{dy}{dt}}$
I was given the following ODE:
$$\begin{align}\diff+2y&=1 \\ \diff&=-2y+1\\ \frac{dy}{-2y+1}&=dt\end{align} $$

Then I was given the following initial condition: $y(0)=\frac{5}2$. I began to answer the following questions, implicitly, and explicitly solve the ODE.

### Implicit Result

I then decided to take the integral of both sides.
$$\begin{align} 
\int\frac{dy}{-2y+1}&=\int dt \\
\int_{\frac{5}2}^y \frac{ds}{-2s+1}&=\int_{0}^{t}dv \\
[\frac{\ln\vert-2s+1\rvert}{-2}]\Bigg\vert_{\frac{5}2}^y&=t \\ 
-\frac{\ln\lvert-2y+1\rvert}{2}+\frac{\ln(4)}{2}&=t
\end{align}$$
Thus, this being the implicit solution:

> $$-\frac{\ln\lvert-2y+1\rvert}{2}=t-\frac{\ln(4)}2$$
> To bring it into the explicit form.
> $$\begin{align}\ln\lvert -2y+1\rvert &= \ln(4) - 2t \\ -2y+1&=e^{\ln(4)-2t}=e^{\ln(4)}e^{-2t} \\ y&=\frac{4e^{-2t}-1}2\end{align}$$

Is my method, and answer correct?

### Edit 1

How do we account for the different various solutions that can be used in this given the separable ODE that I was given in this case? I am going off the idea that it may be due to the absolute value sign, and yes I realized I made a sign mistake in my work initially.

Comment: I think you have a sign mixed up somewhere, the correct solution is $ y = 2 e^{-2x} + \frac{1}{2}$. In general you can always check your answer to an ODE by substitution.

Comment: Yeah I just graphed it lol

Comment: @corner3 Yes I agree, but I substituted in two expressions $\frac{-4e^x+1}{2}$, and $\frac{4e^x+1}{2}$, and they both work

Comment: @corner3 Could that be when I break the absolute value sign giving me two solutions

Comment: I don't think both solutions work.

Comment: @corner3 https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yk875snnzb Solution 1 and Solution 2 https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iu8bnu2xnh

Comment: if you substitute $t = 0$ you will get two different $y$ values. One of your solutions gives the correct $y$ value and the other does not. Therefore one of the solutions you presented does not solve the differential equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, a better method that avoids absolute values in the log.

$y' + 2y=1 \implies (e^{2t}y)'=e^{2t}\implies \int_0^t (e^{2s}y(s))'\, ds=\int_0^t e^{2s}\, ds$

so $e^{2t}y(t)-y(0)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{2t}-1)$. Therefore,
$$
y(t)=y(0)e^{-2t}+\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-2t})=\frac{1}{2}(1+4e^{-2t}).
$$

Comment: Yes I understand this, however, how can we retract the family of solutions which are present, such as the ones I presented https://www.desmos.com/calculator/as6vpdcqkt , and  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nbhdruza4c .

Comment: So I am going to edit my question but good answer, I am going to edit how do we account for the different solutions that can be presented.+1

Answer (score 2):

Starting from this line of your answer:
$$\int_{\frac{5}2}^y \frac{ds}{-2s+1}=\int_{0}^{t}dv \\$$
$$-\frac 12[{\ln\vert s-\dfrac 12\rvert}]\Bigg\vert_{\frac{5}2}^y=t \\ 
$$
$$\ln|y-\dfrac 12| -\ln 2=-2t $$
$$ y-\dfrac 12 = 2e^{-2t}  $$
$$\implies  y=\dfrac 12 + 2e^{-2t}  $$

Comment: +1 I like your answer. But I have modified my question.

Comment: Thank you @EnlightenedFunky you're welcomed

Answer (score 2):

The $+1$ is annoying you ?

Well this is a linear ODE so solve the homogeneous equation $y'+2y=0\iff y(t)=Ce^{-2t}$

Then add a particular solution of equation with RHS, which here is simply the constant $\frac 12$ (since $y'=0$ in that case, so $2y=1$ remains).

Finally determine $C$ for initial condition $y(0)=\frac 52=\frac 12+Ce^0\iff C=2$

Thus $$y(t)=\frac 12+2e^{-2t}$$

Sometimes it is good to come back to basics...

Comment: Nothing is annoying me, I give everyone +1s its just I am more recently active on the site due to the corona virus, and for starters I upvote every answer that is not a math above me on a question I ask I just liked that in this post there was lots of feedback on things that made me think about the problem. So no nothing is annoying me, I am am here to learn math from those experienced.

Comment: lol, the +1 I was referring to was the one in $-2y+1$ on denominator.